# MySQL not returning valid Json

Tags: mysql, json

Using MySQL Server, I have a simple SELECT statement and need to return Json.  All I've found so far is the JSON_OBJECT syntax like this:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 
'Id', Id, 
'Name', Name, 
'State', State)
FROM ACustomer;
```

Which returns this:

```
{"Id": 1, "Name": "Ajax", "State": "WA"}
{"Id": 2, "Name": "Bluebell", "State": "TX"}
{"Id": 3, "Name": "Cornpops", "State": "CA"}
```

but it needs to return valid Json like this:

```
[
{"Id": 1, "Name": "Ajax", "State": "WA"},
{"Id": 2, "Name": "Bluebell", "State": "TX"},
{"Id": 3, "Name": "Cornpops", "State": "CA"}
]
```

In SQL Server we add this to the end of the select statement and everything is formatted perfectly:

```
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the JSON_ARRAYAGG syntax like this:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT( 
'Id', Id, 
'Name', Name, 
'State', State))
FROM ACustomer;
```

I know, this is not documented well and you would think this would be much more common.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should note that the OP query returns multiple rows -- one for each JSON object -- while this solution returns a **single row** with all objects assembled into a single JSON array. Both queries are correct, depending on the result that is needed.